# debian service vs /etc/init.d/script

Tags: tomcat, debian, sh

I'm trying to install tomcat using [these]https://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-debian/ instructions. Accordingly, I create a shell script inside the /etc/init.d directory:

```
#!/bin/sh
export CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat9
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk8
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH

start() {
    echo "Starting tomcat 9"
    /bin/su -s /bin/bash tomcat -c $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
}
end() {
    echo "Stopping tomcat 9"
    /bin/su -s /bin/bash tomcat -c $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
}

case "$1" in
    start|stop) $1;;
    restart) start; stop;;
    *) echo "Usage : <start|stop|restart>";;
esac
exit 0
```

Permissions of this file looks like:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 493 Oct 17 15:00 tomcat

I can run this file using the full path (/etc/init.d/tomcat). However, if I continue with the web instructions, I add this file (sudo update-rc.d tomcat defaults), and should then be able to run it using: sudo service tomcat start.
I get the help message using sudo service tomcat, but nothing when adding start/stop/restart. I found a similar question that recommended using a systemctl command, but I don't have a good understanding of what these commands do, or why I should set up my script in this way. Any clarity would be appreciated.

Comment: First of all, what verios of Debian do you have? For the latest release (Debian 8 Jessie) tomcat 8 is available in official repo:
`tomcat8/stable 8.0.14-1+deb8u3 all
  Apache Tomcat 8 - Servlet and JSP engine`